Unable to design a correct layout in flutter
I'm trying to make a task app with Flutter and Firebase.
I'm not the best for designing so I took a design from Dribbble that i'm trying to copy for my app.
Here is the link of the design.
Dribbble link
Here is the page I'm trying to copy :
Page screenshot
Here is the code I did at the moment : (it's actually not working)
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final String userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("Users")
                        .doc(userID)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                      }
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return const Text("Erreur");
                      }
                      return Text.rich(
                        TextSpan(
                          text: "Bonjour,\n",
                          style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                            fontSize: 40,
                            height: 1.25,
                          ),
                          children: [
                            TextSpan(
                              text: snapshot.data!.data()!["name"],
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  // Column de gauche
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: ListView(
                      children: const [],
                    ),
                  ),

                  // Column de droite
                  SizedBox(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I don't really know how to do the same layout cause I have to split the screen in 2 parts and there is ListView.builder (in my code there is only a ListView) who needs a fixed size.
Edit :
Here is the looking of my app now (cause I wasn't able to find a solution by my own)
Here is the full code of the page (don't mind of the Firebase code) :
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/components/my_task_tile.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/pages/account_page.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/utilities/task_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final String userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final TaskService _ts = TaskService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    // Message de bienvenue
                    StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("Users")
                          .doc(userID)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Shimmer.fromColors(
                            baseColor: const Color.fromRGBO(224, 224, 224, 1),
                            highlightColor: Colors.grey,
                            child: Text.rich(
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "Bonjour,\n",
                                style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                  fontSize: 40,
                                  height: 1.25,
                                ),
                                children: const [
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Nom",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Erreur");
                        }
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => AccountPage()));
                          },
                          child: Text.rich(
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "Bonjour,\n",
                              style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                fontSize: 40,
                                height: 1.25,
                              ),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: snapshot.data!.data()!["name"],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),

                    // Bouton pour ajouter une tâche
                    GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        _ts.addTask(context);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            top: BorderSide(
                              width: 1.5,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                            ),
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                              width: 1.5,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                            ),
                            left: BorderSide(
                              width: 1.5,
                              color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                            ),
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                            left: Radius.circular(18.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            // Icon +
                            const Icon(
                              Icons.add,
                              size: 30,
                            ),

                            // Texte
                            Text(
                              "Ajouter une tâche",
                              style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                fontSize: 15,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: Divider(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25.0),
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("Users")
                        .doc(userID)
                        .collection("Tasks")
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Shimmer.fromColors(
                          baseColor: const Color.fromRGBO(224, 224, 224, 1),
                          highlightColor: Colors.grey,
                          child: GridView.builder(
                            gridDelegate:
                                const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                            ),
                            itemCount: null,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return MyTaskTile(
                                taskTitle: "Task Title",
                                taskIndex: index,
                                isTaskDone: false,
                                taskTheme: null,
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      if (snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty ||
                          snapshot.data == null) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              // Illustration
                              Image.asset("assets/no_task.png"),

                              // Texte
                              Text(
                                "Vous n'avez aucune tâche.",
                                style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                  fontSize: 30,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return GridView.builder(
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                        ),
                        itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length ?? 0,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return MyTaskTile(
                            taskTitle: snapshot.data!.docs[index]["title"],
                            taskIndex: index,
                            isTaskDone: snapshot.data!.docs[index]["state"],
                            taskTheme: snapshot.data!.docs[index]["theme"],
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

How can I replace my GridView.builder and change some of the placement of other widget to get the looking that I want ?
If someone knows how i can copy the same page or just help me doing it, it would be very nice !

Define and declare stream outside build method. Otherwise whenever widget build it will add a new snapshot listener. And do remove the listener in dispose. For layout like yours try to use flutter_staggered_grid_view: ^0.7.0 or use two listview for  your two list. Make their physics NeverScrollableScrollPhysics and wrap it with another listview Or singlechildscrollview. But there is always better method so try them out.

How would you use GridView here, I have to add a button "Add a task" (look at the design).

@Fuiry I am talking about flutter_staggered_grid_view not the gridview.Check out this package first.

If I use "flutter_staggered_grid_view" and I specify my button "Add a task" for the second index of my builder, my button will be scrollable but I want a fix button.
Correct me if I'm wrong (and sorry if I'm not really understandable, I'm not from an english speaking country)

So what you want to do is an floating button. Then my only suggestion would be use a sizebox in staggered grid. And cover whole grid with a stack. Determine the size of that sizebox and position your add your task btn accordingly in stack.

Use MasonryGridView.count from flutter_staggered_grid_view . Make crossAxisCount as 2.And give item a size. At index 1 we will add a sizebox with predefined height. For it width it will me screen width/2 - spacing and padding. Now you have a sizebox and it's size. Now cover this masonary grid with stack. Position an add task btn at top-right with same size as predefined sizebox. And it will produce almost what you wanted. You need to adjust few things and experiment with it according to your needs.

I just edited my question again.
Forget the issue I was facing about the height of my Container, we will fix it later.
So, as you can see, I just have to edit some things about my code but the base is already done.
I just don't understand how I can have a blank space behind the Positionned Button without any error, I tried some things but I didn't found the solution.
I hope you can help me again, I'm really sorry about making you losing time, I'm starting with Flutter and I'm trying my best to become better.

You used gridview. In the answer I mentioned to use masonry grid. And for the positioned btn you can wrap the widget inside the positioned widget with another container,give it some padding and color. But it will not look good because this is an overlay and having space around it will look bad when scrolling items are behind it. And according to you design also the add task btn should be at top of other items when grid is scrolled. I'll add some mock design for you when I can find time but I would suggest if specify the error you mentioned.

"I have come up with an idea. I plan to add an "Add a task" button at the first index of the MasonryGridView. This way, all of the tasks will be generated with their indexes - 1, which will prevent me from skipping the first task of my users. I will keep you updated and modify my questions as I work towards finding a solution."

I shared the answer to my own question. Take a look if you're interested. I utilized your suggestions and tailored them for my specific needs. Thank you again for your time :)

I would like to share the code that helped me solve my problem:
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/components/my_task_tile.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/pages/account_page.dart';
import 'package:db_todoapp/utilities/task_service.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_staggered_grid_view/flutter_staggered_grid_view.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:shimmer/shimmer.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final String userID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  final TaskService _ts = TaskService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    // Message de bienvenue
                    StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("Users")
                          .doc(userID)
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return Shimmer.fromColors(
                            baseColor: const Color.fromRGBO(224, 224, 224, 1),
                            highlightColor: Colors.grey,
                            child: Text.rich(
                              TextSpan(
                                text: "Bonjour,\n",
                                style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                  fontSize: 40,
                                  height: 1.25,
                                ),
                                children: const [
                                  TextSpan(
                                    text: "Nom",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return const Text("Erreur");
                        }
                        return GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute(
                                    builder: (context) => AccountPage()));
                          },
                          child: Text.rich(
                            TextSpan(
                              text: "Bonjour,\n",
                              style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                fontSize: 40,
                                height: 1.25,
                              ),
                              children: [
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: snapshot.data!.data()!["name"],
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    ),

                    StreamBuilder(
                      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection("Users")
                          .doc(userID)
                          .collection("Tasks")
                          .snapshots(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                            ConnectionState.waiting) {
                          return const SizedBox();
                        }
                        if (snapshot.data == null ||
                            snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              _ts.addTask(context);
                            },
                            child: Container(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                border: Border(
                                  top: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1.5,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                                  ),
                                  bottom: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1.5,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                                  ),
                                  left: BorderSide(
                                    width: 1.5,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                                  left: Radius.circular(18.0),
                                ),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  // Icon +
                                  const Icon(
                                    Icons.add,
                                    size: 30,
                                  ),

                                  // Texte
                                  Text(
                                    "Ajouter une tâche",
                                    style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }
                        return const SizedBox();
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                child: Divider(),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),
                  child: StreamBuilder(
                    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection("Users")
                        .doc(userID)
                        .collection("Tasks")
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState ==
                          ConnectionState.waiting) {}
                      if (snapshot.data == null ||
                          snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                        return Center(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              // Illustration
                              Image.asset("assets/no_task.png"),

                              // Texte
                              Text(
                                "Vous n'avez aucune tâche.",
                                style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                  fontSize: 30,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                ),
                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                      return MasonryGridView.count(
                        itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length + 1,
                        crossAxisCount: 2,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          if (index == 0) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                              child: MyTaskTile(
                                taskTitle: snapshot.data!.docs[index]["title"],
                                taskIndex: index,
                                isTaskDone: snapshot.data!.docs[index]["state"],
                                taskTheme: snapshot.data!.docs[index]["theme"],
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          if (index == 1) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                              child: GestureDetector(
                                onTap: () {
                                  _ts.addTask(context);
                                },
                                child: Container(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    border: Border(
                                      top: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1.5,
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                                      ),
                                      bottom: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1.5,
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                                      ),
                                      left: BorderSide(
                                        width: 1.5,
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(189, 189, 189, 1),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.horizontal(
                                      left: Radius.circular(18.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: [
                                      // Icon +
                                      const Icon(
                                        Icons.add,
                                        size: 30,
                                      ),

                                      // Texte
                                      Text(
                                        "Ajouter une tâche",
                                        style: GoogleFonts.exo2(
                                          fontSize: 15,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                          return Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                            child: MyTaskTile(
                              taskTitle: snapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]
                                  ["title"],
                              taskIndex: index - 1,
                              isTaskDone: snapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]
                                  ["state"],
                              taskTheme: snapshot.data!.docs[index - 1]
                                  ["theme"],
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

The Firebase code is not important; the layout is what matters most.
Thanks to everyone who helped me with comments/answers, and thank you Ultranmus for taking the time to assist me!

Just curious you wanted the add task to overlay right? But in your code the btn is part of grid and is Scrollable

This feedback is provided as part of a review task: Notes of thanks are not encouraged on stackoverflow. If you found a comment useful please make sure to upvote that comment instead.

Yes at the beginning I wanted the button to be on top of everything else but when I was trying to accomplish that, the result wasn't satisfying. So I decided to just place the button in the MadonryGridView.

Just as i mentioned in my comment using flutter_staggered_grid_view together with stack can produce same kind of design. Check below code, it produce what you wanted. But you need to set size accordingly in code.
Stack(
        children: [
          MasonryGridView.count(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            crossAxisCount: 2,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            crossAxisSpacing: 16,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              if (index == 1) {
                return const SizedBox(
                  height: 150,
                );
              }
              return Container(
                height: 300,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius:  BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
          Positioned(
            right: 0,
            top: 15,
            child: Container(
              height: 150,
              width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width * 0.5 - 8, // half of screen size - half of cross axis padding in MasonryGridView will give its width
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey),
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20)),
              ),
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              child: const Icon(Icons.add),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )

Result



Nice ! It's almost what I want ! I'll try to reproduce that for my own case.
But, is there a way to avoir having a red Container behind the button ?

Red is just the color I gave to container. You can give it anything you want. Or do you mean something else by not showing the red container?

I mean, if you scroll down, you won't have the gap behind the button cause you created the gap into the MasonryGridView.count.
So is there a way to everytime have a blank area behind the button ?
That was my question, I guess it's possible adding a Positionned blank Container in the stack right behind the button but I didn't try yet cause I'm working on something else in the app.

If you don't want to show red container on top of btn when scrolling, either wrap a btn with another container which cover top padding and set it's color as White. Or don't give any padding in top of gridview. It all depends on your use case.

I'm facing an issue.
I tried to set the gap in the GridView at first index but it means the first element of my MansoryGridView won't appear.
So I tried to wrap my Positionned button in a Container with some Padding and I set the color of the Container the same as my Scaffold background but it looks very bad imo.
I'm facing an other issue, whatever height I'm setting to my TaskTile it stays the same in my MasonryGridView.
(Look at my post, I'll edit it to show you).

It would be good if you can show some image/video of your prblm. And the masonary grid view calculate it's child size depending upon its content. If you don't assign it any size it will take the content size but if you give it some size it will take that. And i really didn't understand what you meant that you assign height to container and you don't have control over it

I'm not at home actually but I'll try to explain better when I can.

try to use GridView.builder, maybe could fix your issue

How would you use GridView.builder here ? Cause I have to put a button "Add a task".

then you must to write a function like to say if index == 1 then show me the container with the Add task  and call it after the builder

Yes, I understand, but if I put my "Add a task" button directly in my GridView.builder at index 1 for example, the button will be scrollable.
I want a fixed button in my interface. And if I say "neverScrollable" for the GridView.builder, my list of tasks won't be scrollable as well.

GridView.builder is a good solution, but for that exact look I think you need to have 2 lists next to each other.
if I didn't use 2 lists next to each other the date  would be:

example of what I wanted:

example of my code:
Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  margin:EdgeInsets.only(top: 10) ,
                  child: ListView(
                    //listview has default top padding
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                      children: [
                        //dates
                        Container(
                          child: Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [


                             Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    for (var destination in destenationsList)
                                    // your codee
                                    // your codee
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              //destinations
                              Container(
                                width: s.width*0.8,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    for (var destination in destenationsList)
                                    // your codee
                                    // your codee
                                      
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ),]
                  ),
                ),
              ),


Yeah, I was thinking the same so I tried with ListView.builder but I was getting some errors and I wasn't able to fix it by my own so that's why I'm asking help here.

@Furiy I have a almost similar example ill edit the answer
